# Arguments in read.delim when used in lapply

Tags: r, csv, import, lapply

I'm using the following code to read a set of CSV files:

```
csvfiles = list.files(pattern = "*.csv", path = "./Data/", 
                      full.names = TRUE)
## Merge into one object
myfiles = lapply(csvfiles, read.delim)
```

I would like to pass some arguments to the read.delim function in order to skip a set of initial rows, define delimiter and so on but whenever I try doing this R returns an error, as illustrated below:

```
> myfiles = lapply(csvfiles, read.delim(skip = 2))
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

What would the correct syntax to modify the parameters of the **read.delim** function when used in conjunction with the **lapply**, as illustrated above?

Comment: something like this: `lapply(csvfiles, read.delim,skipe=2)`

Comment: That's true I may use it.