# Using lapply with read.csv and a pipe delimiter

Tags: r, lapply

I have two vectors of filenames, `sample_files` and `actual_files`.  Each vector contains the filepaths of 4 files.  In `sample_files`, each file is a .csv file and when I call `lapply(sample_files, read.csv)`, I get a list with four dataframes as expected.

However, with the `actual_files` vector, each file is a .txt file that is double-pipe delimited (blurgh) and I get the below error when calling `lapply(actual_files, read.csv(sep="|"))`

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
: argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

I tried reading in each file separately with `read.csv(filename, sep="|")` and it created the dataframe, no problem.

What am I doing wrong with the second `lapply` call to get that error?

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958505/arguments-in-read-delim-when-used-in-lapply) question but it hasn't been answered.

thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the answer at the question you linked to that appears in the comments?

Comment: I think it may be your location of the "sep" argument. try: `lapply(actual_files, read.csv, sep="|")` or alternatively: `purrr::map(files, ~read.csv(.x, sep="|"))`

Comment: @mattL thank you!! that's it.